# Blur/Modify WhatsApp messages in Android

Tags: android, accessibility, whatsapp

I'm developing an Android application that utilizes accessibility services to interact with WhatsApp. The app's functionality involves blurring WhatsApp chats, with the ability for users to click on the blurred area to reveal the actual content.

I've developed a code snippet that successfully extracts WhatsApp messages. However, I'm encountering difficulty implementing the feature to blur or modify the message content with random values, such as asterisks.

```
package com.example.test

import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo

class MyAccessibilityService : AccessibilityService() {

    override fun onAccessibilityEvent(event: AccessibilityEvent) {
        if (event.eventType == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED) {
            if (event.packageName == "com.whatsapp") {
                // Check if the chat interface is opened
                val rootNode = rootInActiveWindow
                rootNode?.let {
                    val messageContent = extractMessageContent(it)
                    if (messageContent != null) {
                        // Now you have the message content, you can process it as needed
                        // For demonstration, we'll just print it
                        println("WhatsApp Message Content: $messageContent")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun extractMessageContent(rootNode: AccessibilityNodeInfo): String? {
        val messageNodes = mutableListOf<String>()
        traverseNode(rootNode, messageNodes)
        return if (messageNodes.isNotEmpty()) {
            messageNodes.joinToString(separator = "\n")
        } else {
            null
        }
    }

    private fun traverseNode(node: AccessibilityNodeInfo, messageNodes: MutableList<String>) {
        // Check if the node is a TextView and has non-empty text
        if (node.className == "android.widget.TextView" && node.text != null) {
            // Add the text content to the list
            messageNodes.add(node.text.toString())
        }
        // Traverse child nodes recursively
        for (i in 0 until node.childCount) {
            val childNode = node.getChild(i)
            childNode?.let {
                traverseNode(childNode, messageNodes)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onInterrupt() {}

}
```